# AWS MySQL RDS instance becomes unresponsive and getting restarted automatically

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a AWS MySQL RDS instance which is about 1.7T in size. Sometimes it becomes unresponsive and no operations can be performed.

1. CPU utilization, Write IOPS, read IOPS, queue depth, write throughput, write latency and read latency drops to zero.
2. Number of connections get piled up.
3. "Show engine innodb status" hangs
4. Lot of queries (around 25 for each) by rdsadmin which are in hang state.

   ```
   SELECT count(*) from mysql.rds_replication_status WHERE action = 'reset slave' and master_host is NULL and master_port is NULL GROUP BY action_timestamp,called_by_user,action,mysql_version,master_host,master_port ORDER BY action_timestamp LIMIT 1;

   SELECT NAME, VALUE FROM mysql.rds_configuration;
   ```
5. After sometime, instance gets rebooted automatically with following error.

   MySQL restart initiated to address MySQL induced log backup issues. Note that as part of this resulution, a DB Snapshot will be performed after MySQL completes restarting.

[image]

What can be the issue? This happens quite often. Sometimes, for our surprise, this happens in off-peak times too.

Comment: Have you tried asking the AWS support?

Comment: Yes. Their response is not positive as we do not have any support subscription yet.

Comment: Are you opening connections, starting transactions, doing updates then not closing the transaction or connection?

Comment: Actually this is not limited to one instance. We observe this behavior both in master servers and slave servers, where slave servers basically has only read load. According to the graphs, we observed that connections get increased just after cpu graph drops to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve this issue by upgrading the instances to 5.6.34.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and raised an issue with AWS Support. Got the following explanation:

---

The RDS Monitoring service discovered issue regarding backing up Binary Logs of your databases which is critical for Point in Time Restore (PITR) feature. To mitigate this issue and in order to avoid data corruption, RDS monitoring restarted the  RDS instance and hence a restart was automatically triggered. In order to make sure that there is no data loss it took a snapshot of DB instance.

Although the RDS instance was multi-AZ it didn't fail over because of following reason:

Multi AZ has 2 criteria:
1- Single Box Experience, which means that Customer always finds his data even after failover.
2- Higher Availability than Single AZ.

So both criteria have to be present when AWS monitoring service takes the Decision to failover to the standby instance, but in your case AWS monitoring service noticed some risk that can cause data loss after the failover and that is why it took the decision to reboot instead of failing over.

---

Hope this helps. This has happened to me 3 times in last one week though.

Comment: Hi Anshul, Thanks for your response. Looks like they have indeed provided you an explanation, but did they get back to you with a resolution or a workaround to avoid/stop this? In our case, this happens almost on every other week.

Comment: I have asked for it. Waiting for reply.

Comment: Great. Please let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Anshul, Did AWS get back to you on this?

Answer (score 0):

check your db maintenance window timing  i mean when your schedule maintenance is happening , and note at what time this issue happening is it happening in regular interval or randomly .

check both mysql error logs and slow query logs.

if possible paste the suspected issue here

Comment: Nothing important in the logs during that period. Also, at one instance, we brought down the applications and killed all sessions and waited for database to respond. But database refused to respond and ultimately automatic restart happened.  (certain commands work such as KILL and "show open tables", "show processlist")

Comment: have you checked your schedule maintenance timing  , 

can you paste your show processlist output of that time if you have  it

Comment: I checked the maintenance window, that does not in line with the incidents. In fact incidents do not have any pattern. Process list contains lot of queries in "Opening tables" state and additionally following queries (25 each)

Comment: SELECT count(*) from mysql.rds_replication_status WHERE action = 'reset slave' and master_host is NULL and master_port is NULL GROUP BY action_timestamp,called_by_user,action,mysql_version,master_host,master_port ORDER BY action_timestamp LIMIT 1;

SELECT NAME, VALUE FROM mysql.rds_configuration;

Comment: SELECT NAME, VALUE FROM mysql.rds_configuration;